# Java 1.4 used with maven jar plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

In some of my maven modules (example myChild) I use maven-jar-plugin to create some additional jar, named here my-plugin.jar. This my-plugin.jar should be only the part of the entire module - myChild.jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns=...>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>myChild</artifactId>

<parent>
<groupId>org.group</groupId>
<artifactId>myParent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-plugins-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>......</include>
                    </includes>
                    <finalName>my-plugin</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
 ...........
</dependencies>
```

When I want to use myChild module in the another maven module (example myExternal) I add the dependency on myChild. But the compilation of myExternal failed because of errors like: `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`. When I removed two @Override annotations, the number of errors decreased by two. It seems that Java 1.4 is used. But parent POM has maven-compiler-plugin with `source` and `target` 1.7.
What more is curious, the myChild module compiles well. But when some other module which uses myChild is compiling, then the above errors occurs.

Comment: maven-compiler-plugin is in [pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section?

Comment: It is in pluginManagement section and in plugins. http://pastebin.com/XAmG2TuR

Comment: configuration should be located in pluginManagment to be visible across all modules. Full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to [published code](https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/7437074) you need to move `maven-compiler-plugin` **configuration** from `plugins` to `pluginsManagement` sections to be visible in all submodules.

### Parent POM sample configuration

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```